# How to get a particular execute detect command to work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When a player has an oak staircase directly in front of them, I would like a command block to place a barrier under them.

The command I have used that fails is:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~1 ~1 ~ minecraft:oak_stairs /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ barrier
```

I will use multiple command blocks with a similar command to make it work on all sides of the player.

I also need a way to where the player leaves the oak stairs it would remove the barrier.

My Minecraft has messed up and nothing I can do can fix it but it cant show my the command block output no matter what I try. Can someone please try and help me with this, nothing I can find helps me at all.

Comment: Please only ask one question.  If you have another question, post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! The game thinks that `/setblock` is the block state, so simply add a value for the oak stair before `/setblock`. <s>Unfortunately, you will need to do it for every block state, unless there is a way of targeting every block type with detect (If there is, please inform me. That would be most useful)</s> Thanks to [IronAnvil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/186522/ironanvil), I can now inform you that to target any oak stair, simply put -1 as the block state.

In this case, you would go

`/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~1 ~1 ~ minecraft:oak_stairs -1 /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ barrier`

which would look for oak stairs facing west, to the east of the player, to then place a barrier underneath.

Hope I could help!

Comment: From [the wiki on execute command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#execute) under the dataValue argument: "Must be a valid block data for that type of block or -1 to match any block data."